# How to build Global app with Elasticbeanstalk and Cloudfront?

Tags: load-balancing, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an api system(api.com) run elasticbeanstalk(singapore region), and I want users in Virginia can be access to api.com with lowest latency. From what I know Cloudfront can do this by put it in front of elb, but I got some issue when deploy for example:

**- api.com cname to elasticbeanstalk url(xxx.elasticbeanstalk.com)

- my cloudfront name: xxx.cloudfront.net with Origin api.com(Use All Edge Locations)**

What I understand is when users in Virginia access to xxx.cloudfront.net will be faster than access to api.com because cloudfront use Edge Locations.

But amazing when I test the result in Virginia:
- api.com took 2s to return the result
- xxx.cloudfront.net took 2.3s to return the result
It's even slower than normal.

What am I wrong and how can I build a system for Global users?

Comment: The reason it could be fast with direct elb(in N Virginia) in Virginia because aws have a DC over there and with cloudfront it's the same speed but takes additional time with user --> CloudFront --> Origin(additional 3 way handshake/ssl etc between cf and origin), you will get good results with cloudfront if try it from different locations.

Comment: Cloudfront wont necessarily make things faster when accessing an origin halfway around the world.